# Python JSON Error

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I am trying to write automated tests for checking JSON requests. So when I run the following the code I am getting a traceback error:

```
json1=query_link1.json
json2 = json.loads(json1)
```

Exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Productapicheck.py", line 45, in <module>
    query_product_api()
  File "Productapicheck.py", line 34, in query_product_api
    json2 = json.loads(json1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/json/__init__.py", line 307, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/json/decoder.py", line 319, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Comment: What is `query_link1.json`? It's not a string or a buffer. Is it a file?

Comment: This question is unanswerable. What is `query_link1`?

Comment: You need to provide more information. Dumping code with no background helps no one.

Answer (score 2):

If `query_link1.json` is a file-like object, you need to use the `json.load()` function instead.

`.loads()` (with `s` at the end) requires that you pass in a string and `query_link1.json` is *not* a string.

If you are using the `requests` library, then you do *not* need to decode the `.json` value on a response, it is automaticaclly decoded for you by the library when you access that attribute.

Comment: Hi, When I used json.load function am getting a diff error now Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Productapicheck.py", line 45, in <module>
    query_product_api()
  File "Productapicheck.py", line 34, in query_product_api
    json2 = json.load(json1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/json/__init__.py", line 264, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: @user1121120: Right, so now we finally have some information. `.json` is *already* decoded from the JSON format.

Comment: SO @Martijn Pieters, Does that means that I do not have to do second statement json2 = json.loads(json1)?

Comment: Thanks @Martijn Pieters. I did this because, when I was trying to find specific json value from the json1 file, Am getting errors like to define json tags. What should I do to remove this error?

Comment: @user1121120: If the request you retrieved *is not JSON encoded* then accessing the `.json` attribute on a response will raise an error. Fix the response in that case.